# Cannot link to BLAS/ATLAS when trying to compile HPCC benchmark

Tags: c, mpi, blas, atlas

I am trying to compile the HPCC benchmark on a small RHEL desktop.  Everything seems fine until linking.  My link command is

```
    mpicc -DAdd_ -DF77_INTEGER=int -DStringSunStyle  -I../../../include \
 -I../../../include/myarch -I/path/to/my/ATLAS_build/include \
-I/usr/include/openmpi-x86_64 -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -funroll-loops \
-W -Wall -lm -o ../../../../hpcc ../../../lib/bugzilla/libhpl.a \
/path/to/my/ATLAS_build/lib/libcblas.a \
/path/to/my/ATLAS_build/lib/libatlas.a -L/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib
```

The link fails with several errors, all related to BLAS/ATLAS objects that the linker can't find.  A few of them are:

```
../../../lib/myarch/libhpl.a(HPL_dcopy.o): In function `HPL_dcopy':
HPL_dcopy.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `dcopy_'
../../../lib/myarch/libhpl.a(HPL_daxpy.o): In function `HPL_daxpy':
HPL_daxpy.c:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `daxpy_'
../../../lib/myarch/libhpl.a(HPL_dscal.o): In function `HPL_dscal':
HPL_dscal.c:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `dscal_'
../../../lib/myarch/libhpl.a(HPL_idamax.o): In function `HPL_idamax':
HPL_idamax.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `idamax_'
../../../lib/myarch/libhpl.a(HPL_dgemv.o): In function `HPL_dgemv':
HPL_dgemv.c:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `dgemv_'
HPL_dgemv.c:(.text+0x136): undefined reference to `dgemv_'
```

Here's what I really don't understand.  Take `dgemv` for instance.  libhpl.a does indeed invoke it:

```
>$ nm libhpl.a | grep dgemv
HPL_dgemv.o:
                 U dgemv_
```

Now, libcblas.a has a reference to it, but needs the version in ATLAS:

```
>$ nm libcblas.a | grep dgemv
cblas_dgemv.o:
                 U ATL_dgemv
```

Finally, does ATLAS have ATL_dgemv?

```
ATL_dgemv.o:
0000000000000000 T ATL_dgemv
```

So, yes, it certainly does.  So `CBLAS` has a `dgemv` that `HPCC` should (I would think) be able to plug into, but it needs `ATL_dgemv`.  But ATLAS has `ATL_dgemv`.  So why can't the linker find everything it needs for `HPCC`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logs indicate that `libhpl.a` needs the `dgemv_` symbol that is not provided either by `libcblas.a` nor `libatlas.a` (I assume your last command was `nm libatlas.a | grep dgemv`).

The trailing underscore in `dgemv_` strongly suggests it requires the Fortran BLAS(and not the C BLAS) library, so you can simply replace `libcblas.a` with `libblas.a`.

IIRC, an other option is to tweak the HPL config and direct it to use cblas instead of (Fortran) BLAS.

Comment: When ATLAS compiles, it does not generate a libblas.a.  However, there is a libf77blas.a.  Right now, our machine is having issues.  But when it is available again, I will give it a shot.  Thanks.

Comment: As I mentioned, ATLAS doesn't produce a libblas.a, just a libf77blas.a.  But it had the objects I needed, so you were basically right.  Thanks,  Also, FYI, as it turns out, a C compiler can't link with libf77blas.a.  It reports a bunch of missing gfortran stuff.  So I had to changed the linker (not the compiler, just the linker) to Fortran.  Thanks!